# In a group with read/write/execute permissions in a folder but cannot cd into it

Tags: linux, permissions

I am currently trying to add users to a git repo I have on a linux machine. I made a group call webdev in which I added user1 and user2 using useradd.I then proceeded to add the group to the folder. I then changed the permissions of the folder using chmod 070. I restart the machine.

Problem

Now I try to cd into the folder I just recently changed permissions for and it says I do not have enough permissions yet I am in the webdev group.

When I list the folder this is what I get

```
 d---rwx--- 3 user1 webdev 4096 jun 22 14:18 : Git Repo
```

In etc/groups it clearly lists user1 and user2 in the group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unix permissions actually work this way:

```
if (you are root) {
    you have 'rwx' permissions for any folder and 'rw' and possibly 'x' for any file
} else if (you are file's owner) {
    only 'owner' permissions apply to you
} else if (list of groups you belong to includes file's group) {
    only 'group' permissions apply to you
} else {
    only 'other' permissions apply to you
}
```

So if you are `user1` and folder's owner is `user1` and folder has `'---rwx---'` permissions, then owner permissions (`'---'`) apply to you and you have no access.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue isn't git-related. Instead of running `chmod 070` on your directory, you should've used `chmod 770`. Having no `rwx` permissions for the `user1` might be overriding the group permissions, thereby locking `user1` out. Can `user2` get in?

Oddly enough, when I do this test on Ubuntu 12.04, OS X Mountain Lion, and OS X Yosemite, I'm locked out, but not on OS X Lion.

Comment: User 2 cannot get in but I did not know user permissions work like Roman described above.